# How to insert a string with chr(30) into a field in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

How to set a string with chr(30) into a field in SQL?

ie, I want to do as follows:

```
update TABLE_name set col_name="string1"+chr(30)+"string2";
```

for reference)

I think chr(30) would be a record separator.

my DBMS version : 5.5.64-MariaDB

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, using [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [`CHAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char):

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = CONCAT('string1', CHAR(30), 'string2');
```

Comment: Thanks!  I really appreciate your help!    It was char(30) not chr(30) I had to use.  I really appreciate !

Comment: I am really sorry to Sebastian Brosch. I am not used to this site.

Comment: Thanks to Scaratte ! :)